# Unicode errror from Haystack indexing

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, unicode-string

I've got a Django system with haystack & elasticsearch powered search. More specifically I'm using django-cms and aldryn search to integrate search with the CMS.

```
aldryn-search==0.3.0
Django==1.10.7
django-cms==3.4.3
django-haystack==2.6.0
elasticsearch==2.4.1
requests==2.13.0
requests-aws4auth==0.9
```

The whole process for indexing haystack is controlled by third party apps, but I've never experienced this before so hopefully can find a fix.

When running `update_index` for haystack there's some unicode issues;

```
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 785, in bulk
doc_type, '_bulk'), params=params, body=self._bulk_body(body))
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 327, in perform_request
status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 68, in perform_request
response = self.session.request(method, url, data=body, timeout=timeout or self.timeout)
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
timeout=timeout
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/Users/mwalker/Sites/myproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 356, in _make_request
conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1093, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1049, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 891, in _send_output
msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1815: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Haystack settings;

```
awsauth = AWS4Auth(TBH_AWS_ACCESS_KEY, TBH_AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_S3_REGION, 'es')
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch2_backend.Elasticsearch2SearchEngine',
        'URL': 'https://search.eu-west-1.es.amazonaws.com/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'myproj_dev',
        'TIMEOUT': 30,
        'KWARGS': {
            'port': 443,
            'http_auth': awsauth,
            'use_ssl': True,
            'verify_certs': True,
            'connection_class': elasticsearch.RequestsHttpConnection,
        }
    },
}
```

Once the process hits urllib3 at the following code block;

```
# conn.request() calls httplib.*.request, not the method in
# urllib3.request. It also calls makefile (recv) on the socket.
if chunked:
    conn.request_chunked(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
else:
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
```

I can see the issue with the data;

```
>>> httplib_request_kw['body'][1815]
'�'
>>> httplib_request_kw['body'].decode('utf-8')[1815]
u'-'
```

Is there some kind of monkey patching or adjustments I could make to the haystack setup to ensure decoding of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/fields.py`, `convert` function (near line 209). Try to add:

```
if isinstance(value, str):
   value = value.decode("utf-8")
```

Full class code after change:

```
class CharField(SearchField):
    field_type = 'string'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('facet_class') is None:
            kwargs['facet_class'] = FacetCharField

        super(CharField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def prepare(self, obj):
        return self.convert(super(CharField, self).prepare(obj))

    def convert(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None

        if isinstance(value, str):
            value = value.decode("utf-8")

        return six.text_type(value)
```

Comment: Oddly, I had some issues with the AWS keys in use, which when resolved seemed to resolve the unicode issue themselves. So although this would have fixed it, I didn't need to monkey patch anything in the end. Which is still confusing me!